# count occurrences in for loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, for-loop

For example.

If James, Joe and John visited a shop how could I count how many people visited the shop in the loop instead of displaying the data 3 times. Really i need to count how many B.customer_name's there are in that 1 shop. So for each customer_name count the number of occurrences.

```
    For Each A As customer_service.customer_details In C.customers

        Dim B As customer_service.customer = customer_dl.customer_details(A.customer_id)
        display_customer.Text &= "<p>" & A.customer_shops & " " & B.customer_name & "</p>"

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To get each customer by themselves, and then get the count, you typically use `GroupBy` to get each customer's data together, then `Count` to get the count`.

In C#, something like:

```
foreach (var customerVisits in C.customers.GroupBy(c => c.Name))
{
   int visitCount = customerVisits.Count()
}
```

Comment: Which in VB would be something like:
    For Each customerVisits In C.customers.GroupBy(Function(c) c.Name) : Dim visitCount = customerVisits.Count() : Next

(the declaration of visitCount could include the type depending on whether you want it to infer the type or squawk if you think you know and turn out to be wrong)